# MVC avoid page refreshing multiple adding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

The action in my controller add an item to the DB, 
I have to avoid the the page refreshing permit to insert multiple istance on the DB.
My url is:

```
/Create/?order=123
```

Is it possible to return the view without the parameters? 
In this way the page refres will not call the create method.

Comment: Your url is a GET method and should not be changing data in a database. That's what a POST method is for.

Comment: PRG Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most correct way - create and modify entity by means of POST method.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(someModel model)
 {
         ...
     return View("differentView",model);
 }
```

And If you follow this strategy is not to encounter this problem

Comment: You could simply return a different view as a confirmation, like: `return View("ItemCreated");`

Comment: Can I pass a model to the different view?